# How to wire an Ibanez RG170 W/5-way switch H-S-H

Tags: electric-guitar, wiring

I have an Ibanez RG170 electric guitar with a volume knob and a tone knob and a 5- way switch and one day I opened up the back and noticed that one of the Humbuckers was never actually hooked up at all the wires to it weren't even stripped I forget why I desoldered what was already hooked up by I did. Regardless, I got the Single pickup working by taking the "white" wire and I sphere it to the first tab on the switch but I don't know how to get the two Humbuckers hooked up my guitars configuration is H-S-H if anybody knows how to wire this back up I would really appreciate  the help.

I've included a couple pictures below.

Pic of guitar

[image]

Wiring cavity

[image]

Anything you can contribute is welcome.  Thank You.

Comment: This can probably be of some help: https://www.seymourduncan.com/resources/pickup/wiring-diagrams